# How to ANSI-C cast from unsigned int * to char *?

Tags: c, casting, character-encoding, printf

I want these two print functions to do the same thing:

```
    unsigned int Arraye[] = {0xffff,0xefef,65,66,67,68,69,0};
            char Arrage[] = {0xffff,0xefef,65,66,67,68,69,0};
    printf("%s", (char*)(2+ Arraye));
    printf("%s", (char*)(2+ Arrage));
```

where Array is an unsigned int. Normally, I would change the type but, the problem is that most of the array is numbers, although the particular section should be printed as ASCII. Currently, the unsigned array prints as "A" and the char array prints as the desired "ABCDE".

Comment: Why does your "byte" contains 16 bits?

Comment: I want 0xffff<<1 to be 0xfffe
and
its the canonical representation of my data

Comment: (unsigned int) 0xffff is 0x0000ffff in memory. C strings are null terminated, it won't give what you have expected.

Comment: @Kenny, a byte is _not_ 8 bits, it's defined in the standard as the size of the char types. And for @J16, you're assuming unsigned ints are 32 bit, never a portable assumption.

Comment: @pax of course I know 1 byte is not 8 bits in C standard, but in which architecture nowadays it is not 8 bits *and* OP would encounter? What I meant was the first 2 elements in that may not give what OP wants.

Comment: @paxdiablo, a *char* may not be 8 bits, but a *byte* is 8 bits by definition.

Comment: @Michael, not in the ISO C standard. A byte is as many bits as it takes to store the character. Standards tends to use the term octet for an 8-bit value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the `unsigned int` version will be arranged in memory, assuming 32-bit big endian integers.

```
00 00 ff ff 00 00 ef ef 00 00 00 41 00 00 00 42
00 00 00 43 00 00 00 44 00 00 00 45 00 00 00 00
```

This is how the `char` version will be arranged in memory, assuming 8-bit characters.  Note that `0xffff` does not fit in a `char`.

```
ff ef 41 42 43 44 45 00
```

So you can see, casting is not enough.  You'll need to actually convert the data.

If you know that your system uses 32-bit `wchar_t`, you can use the `l` length modifier for `printf`.

```
printf("%ls", 2 + Arraye);
```

This is NOT portable.  The alternative is to copy the `unsigned int` array into a `char` array by hand, something like this:

```
void print_istr(unsigned int const *s)
{
    unsigned int const *p;
    char *s2, *p2;
    for (p = s; *p; p++);
    s2 = xmalloc(p - s + 1);
    for (p = s, p2 = s2; *p2 = *p; p2++, p++);
    fputs(s2, stdout);
    free(s2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I ended up doing something like this.

Comment: I suggested another solution because I do not like functions that allocate memory for temporaries.

Answer (score 0):

As Dietrich said, a simple cast will not do, but you don't need a complicated conversion either. Simply loop over your array.

```
uint_t Arraye[] = {0xffff,0xefef,65,66,67,68,69,0};
  char Arrage[] = {0xffff,0xefef,65,66,67,68,69,0};

uint_t *p;
for(p = Arraye+2; p; p++)
  printf("%c", p);

printf("%s", (char*)(2+ Arrage));
```